# React render method being called every time parent rerenders

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component, that I noticed is being rerendered every time the owner component renders, even though the props being passed have not changed.

Is this normal behavior? I thought a component only rerenders if the owner sends in new props, i.e. the props are changed have different values or some internal state changes.

Assuming the above is true are there any tricks to debugging what is changing to cause the component to rerender?

Comment: Could you add a code sample?

Comment: Yea code would be nice - also if the render function which gets called after some state update and the render function includes the child component then it will be rerendered too

Comment: Its a very general question.  The component I noticed this is pretty complex.  The answer below seems to imply that I was wrong, and that render is always called regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of React is to use Virtual DOM above actual DOM. `render()` method in your React Component is used to compute new VD, compare it with previous, and apply diff to AD. And there is a difference between e.g. `React.DOM.div` and your component in the `render()` method of another component - React needs to calculate VD of your component - obviously, due it's `render()` method - even if no props were passed.

However, you can explicitly tell React Component, should it invoke it's `render()` method or not - using the `shouldComponentUpdate()` hook. In `React.createClass()` notation you can use `PureRenderMixin`, which is nothing except next code injection:

```
import shallowEqual from 'react/lib/shallowEqual';

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEqual(nextProps, this.props) || !shallowEqual(nextState, this.state);
}
```

There are some ways to do it in ES6 notation - e.g. inheritance from `PureRenderComponent`, that contains the above hook.

See also https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Comment: The reference to the PureRenderMixin made this much clearer... I think my confusion is probably that I had assumed React ALWAYS assumed things were pure, unless you told it otherwise, not the other way around Thanks